# Field 'id' expected a number but got '(string)

Tags: django

I'm creating a T-shirt shop with variants/colors. In adding to cart, I get the error:
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'woodstock'. Woodstock is the name of the shirt, but I'm passing the cartid to the function. cartid is actually being used in the remove_from_cart function, but I'm not sure why the error is thrown when I push add to cart.
Here's the cart model:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Cart id: %s" %(self.id)

class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variations = models.ManyToManyField(Variation, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    line_total = models.DecimalField(default=10.99, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            return str(self.cart.id)
        except:
            return self.product.name
```

views.py

```
def view(request):
    print("viewing cart")
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        the_id = None
    if the_id:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
        new_total = 0.00
        for item in cart.cartitem_set.all():
            line_total = float(item.product.price) * item.quantity
            new_total += line_total
        request.session['items_total'] = cart.cartitem_set.count()
        cart.total = new_total
        cart.save()

        context = {"cart":cart}
    else:
        empty_message = "Your cart is empty, please keep shopping"
        context = {"empty": True, "empty_message": empty_message}

    template = "cart/view.html"
    return render(request, template, context)


def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    print("add_to_cart pressed")
    request.session.set_expiry(100000000)
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        #create cart id
        new_cart = Cart()
        new_cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
        the_id = new_cart.id
    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass
    product_variations = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        qty = request.POST['qty']
        for item in request.POST:
            key = item
            val = request.POST[key]
            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(product=product, category__iexact=key, title__iexact=val)
                product_variations.append(v)
            except:
                pass
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart, product=product)
        if len(product_variations) > 0:
            cart_item.variations.add(*product_variations)
        cart_item.quantity = qty
        cart_item.save()
        print("cart item added")


        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("carts:cart"))


    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("carts:cart"))

def remove_from_cart(request, id):
    print(id) #this is showing the item name, the reason it's not working. Either traced back to html view or urls.py
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("carts:cart"))
        
    cartitem = CartItem.objects.get(id=id)#error is traced to this line
    cartitem.cart = None
    cartitem.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("carts:cart"))
```

html

```
{% block content %}
<div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
{% if empty %}
  <h1 style="text-align:center;">{{ empty_message }}</h1>
{% else %}

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total: {{ cart.total }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    {% for item in cart.cartitem_set.all %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.product }}
        {% if item.variations.all %}
        <ul>
        {% for var in item.variations.all %}
        <li> {{ var.category|capfirst }} : {{ var.title|capfirst }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
      </td>

      <td>{{ item.product.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
      <td><a href='{% url "carts:remove_from_cart" item.id %}'>Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>

{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py for cart

```
app_name='carts'

urlpatterns =[
    path('cart/', views.view, name='cart'),
    path('cart/<id>/', views.remove_from_cart, name='remove_from_cart'),
    path('cart/<slug:slug>/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),

]
```

One suggestion in researching this problem was to delete migrations and run makemigrations/migrate, but that didn't work for me. Any other suggestions or why item.id is passing the name and not the id?

Comment: `id` is a Python built-in function. While this is not a cause of the error in your program, it is better to avoid using names of built-in functions for naming your own functions and variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `remove_from_cart` url path matches paths like `cart/<id>/` where `id` does not have a type so matches anything, the `add_to_cart` path uses `cart/<slug:slug>/` but because any slug will also match `id` from the previous path this view will ever be used. You need to make these paths unique so that they never match the same path.

One way is to make `id` an integer so that slugs will not match it

```
path('cart/<int:id>/', views.remove_from_cart, name='remove_from_cart'),
path('cart/<slug:slug>/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
```

The better way is to add prefixes to these paths so that they never clash

```
path('cart/remove/<int:id>/', views.remove_from_cart, name='remove_from_cart'),
path('cart/add/<slug:slug>/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
```

Comment: oh my! that did it, so simple, but I was way off on where I was thinking the problem lies. At first, it broke other pieces, but it was an issue with the sessions and existing cart and cartitems. Deleted those out of db logged out and back in and now everythings functioning correctly. Thank you!